# Why using List<T> as stack returns _GrowableList

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Dart. I have implemented list as stack reference for code [here](https://github.com/pallavbohara/fluuter_maze/blob/master/lib/utils/get_answer.dart). I am calculating path from one node to other in graph. Problem with code is it returns _GrowableList on which is either empty or null but my `GetAnswer` do returns a correct list(checked while debugging). Why it automatically converts it into growable, How can I have my normal list?

Here is snippet of code where I am passing my graph start node and end node to instance of `GetAnswer` and storing back result in `path` variable.

[image: source]

Comment: Dart lists are growable by default. You can pass `growable: false` to most constructors to get a fixed-sized list. A `_GrowableList` is still a `List`

Answer (score 2):

That's the real internal type for the list you created. However, it shouldn't really look like this in the tooltip, this is how it looks for me:

[image: Lists in debug tooltips]

If you can provide code that reproduces showing the tooltip like that, I'd love to take a look. Please open a bug in [GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/new).

(It's possible you're on v2.11 of Dart Code - if so, please update to v2.12 and this should be improved)